# How to make a simple Interface using scala

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, interface

My Spark project is on Eclipse and I am using Maven and Scala IDE.
This is my code

```
package bd.spark_app 
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext 
import org.apache.spark.sql._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType 
import scala.io.Source 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray 
import org.apache.log4j._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType}    
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row 
import scala.Array 

object alla { 

  def main(args:Array[String]) = { 
    val conf =newSparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("trying ") 
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 

    val x = sc.textFile("/home/hadoopusr/sampledata") 

    x.map(_.split(" "))
     .map(str => (
       (str.head.head match { 
          case 'M' => "Magazine" 
          case 'B' => "Book" 
          case 'D' => "Dictionary" 
          case _ => ??? 
        }, 
        str.head.drop(1).dropRight(3).toInt
       ), str.last.toInt)
     ) 
    .reduceByKey(_ + _) 
    .map(tuple => (tuple._1._1, tuple._1._2, tuple._2))
```

The result is

```
(Magazine,2003,3),
(Dictionary,2001,24),
(Dictionary,2003,3), 
(Book,2002,1), 
(Magazine,2001,7), 
(Book,2004,10),
(Dictionary,2002,22), 
(Dictionary,2004,10)
```

I would like the result to be in a table

```
TYPE       YEAR COPIES 
Magazine   2003      3
Dictionary 2001     24
Dictionary 2003      3
Book       2002      1
```

And so on...

But I need the table to be in a simple interface.
I am new the scala and haven't find anything about it on ' how to make an interface with scala'

Comment: A couple of things. Never post unformatted code - I have formatted it for you this time, but it was nearly impossible to read. Also it is unclear what you are asking. What do you mean that you want the result "in a table"? An what do you mean that you need it to be "in a simple interface"??

Answer (score 0):

> But I need the table to be in a simple interface.

What is the purpose? to save the data in a database?

You can define a case class as follows, outside your `alla` object:

```
case class Entry(`type`: String, year: Int, copies: Int)
```

and then you replace:

```
      .map(tuple => tuple._1._1, tuple._1._2, tuple._2)
```

by

```
      .map(tuple => Entry(tuple._1._1, tuple._1._2, tuple._2))
```